# 2 GB Ram, but Ubuntu runs slowly and hangs if doing too much

Tags: performance, ram, memory-usage

I think my system more than meets the minimum/recommended requirements for Ubuntu, but its still running slowly. Especially when I try to multitask by having 4-6 windows open, then it becomes quite slow and often hangs completely.

Before this, I was using Linux Mint previously which ran perfectly (but due to some software not working, I've moved to Ubuntu).

My question is, if I replaced my Ubuntu with Xubuntu, will it run faster (equivalent to how Linux Mint was running)? Or do I have to go down to Lubuntu?

Comment: What version an distro are you actually using? Is it xubuntu, lubuntu (because of the tags) or ubuntu. Is it 12.04, 12.10?

Comment: You should have enough RAM to run Ubuntu, what processor and graphics card do you have?

Comment: Maybe give a bit more information about those 4-6 windows. Are they terminal windows running some task within? Or browser windows or video player? That will help us to suggest the next step of action(or question :P).

Comment: @LuisAlvarado I'm using 12.10 I believe, whichever the latest version is. I downloaded it from the site a few hours ago. Not using Xubuntu, using  main Ubuntu

Comment: @iSeth Processor: Intel® Core™ Duo CPU T2450 @ 2.00GHz × 2 , graphics card: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller

Comment: @JohnSiu Pretty much any task, if I have firefox open and also try to play music, or copy files from one folder to another, multitasking seems to hang it pretty quickly.

Comment: In a terminal, run the "free" command, and the last line of output shows swap -- if no swap is used, you are not short of memory.

Comment: @ubfan1 May be that's the thing, I don't have a swap created. If I reinstalled and manually created a swap, is that going to improve things substantially?/

Comment: Try using a swap file first, see how to from "man mkswap"

Answer (score 2):

Running these commands may help in speeding things up a little by freeing some caches, but this won't fix the cause:

```
sudo su -
```

enter your password

```
sync
echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I cannot comment on your question. You may not have to reinstall if you can resize your partitions or have some unallocated space left over to create a swap partition. A swap partition would be advisable with only 2gb of ram. Try using `gparted` perhaps to do this.

Comment: How much of an impact will swap have?

Comment: Quite a lot! I personally find 2gb RAM to be a minimum for ubuntu if you want to do a few things at once. Even 3gb still eats up swap when using eclipse IDE and a browser with a few tabs open. The computer will run faster if it does not have to use swap space, and my other answer will speed give you a little boost when needed.